# How to get Firefox to stop warning about HTTP downloads?

Tags: firefox, http, security-warning

I've read and followed the suggestion in:

[Disable Firefox blocking of HTTP downloads](https://superuser.com/q/1682451/122798)

so, HTTP downloads work. But - Firefox gives me a ridiculous warning against files downloaded using HTTP.

How can I make Firefox not give that warning?

Comment: I do not think the warning is unique to Firefox.

Comment: @John: Well, `wget` doesn't have it :-)

Comment: 1. Perhaps security.warn_submit_secure_to_insecure? See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-80-release-notes . 2. Perhaps browser.safebrowsing.downloads.remote.block_dangerous? See https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/how-safe-browsing-works-in-firefox/ . See https://www.ghacks.net/2015/08/18/a-comprehensive-list-of-firefox-privacy-and-security-settings/ for more. However, I have not tried to turn off that warning, since I prefer an extra notice to malware.